# PHP PDO:odbc Query Result missing Certain Column values

Tags: php, database, pdo, odbc, vertica

I am using PHP PDO:ODBC to connect to Vertica database using Vertica's ODBC driver. The data from the database is being loaded into a PHP array and then loaded up into a HTML table through Javascript.
I am connecting to multiple databases and have multiple queries which populate different tables on my webpage.

My problem is with two different queries. In two queries, i am unable to retrieve the data for a specific column(different for both queries) from the database. e.g:

```
Select columnA,columnB,columnC,columnD from table1
```

I am able to get the values for other columns but not ColumnC. On trying to fetch only ColumnC, the result is still empty.

I have tried to "echo" the array value but it is empty for the column value. There is no error. The strange thing is that the Column's data type is "Varchar/Integer", similar to other columns in the database (others work fine).

I have searched a lot on Google but have found only a few similar issues without any clear diagnosis or solution. Based on one of those solutions i have edited the "ODBC.defaultlrl"(Handling of Long fields) in the "PHP.ini" file with the value "odbc.defaultlrl=65536" , but it doesn't help.

From the ODBC log it appears that the SQL statement is successfully getting the data.

My thinking is that PHP is not handling the fetched columned data properly, but i cannot determine why.
Below is the PHP part relevant to one of the Columns of an SQL statement, which is returned empty.

```
try{
$dsn = "dsn_name";
$pdo = new PDO("odbc:$dsn", "user","password");
}catch (PDOException $exc) {

            // catch the connection error

            echo $exc->getMessage();
            exit();
}
$array_name = array();
$pdo4_name= $pdo->query("SELECT disk_space_used_mb from disk_table");
foreach ($pdo4_name as $row)
        {
            //$str = implode(" ",$row);
            //echo "$row<br>";
            array_push($array4_name,$row[0]);
            echo "$array4_name[0]".",";
        }
```

Comment: That entire fetch loop could be trivially replaced with a simple `$array4_name = $pdo4_name->fetchAll()`. and for your specific case, `var_dump($row)` and see what kind of array keys you're getting. If PDO is returning string-only keys, then `$row[0]` will not exist.

Comment: Thanks "Marc B" for the replacement of loop suggestion. I do need to cleanup/organize a good bit of my code.
About the issue, on trying var_dump($row) i am noticing String keys.
If i only fetch the faulty column on its own in the SQL, then vardump returns nothing at all.
But if i i try to retrieve the faulty column along with good columns, then var dump returns NULL.  e.g:

    ["export_address"]=> NULL [2]=> NULL

Comment: What happens when you run your query in `vsql`?

Comment: The query returns all results fine in vsql, DbViz/JDBC driver and Excel/ODBC driver.

Comment: I have managed to find the reason for this issue with the certain columns.
At the database end the table column field was created with a default data type value of  8254 bytes i.e.  VARCHAR 8254.   Thus PHP PDO:ODBC was not able to handle it. On using the SQL Cast function i am able to cast that column as Varchar 32 and it is being handle fine by PHP. But i would like to know if there is any option at PHP to handle this large column size without have to use SQL Cast?

Comment: @H.Shah - similar happened to me. Field is varchar(50) and PDO was getting "null" for some records. I noticed it happens if the content was close to the field size, but it didn't make sense at first, because some 45 length content was having issue but some 46 wasn't. Then I figured it is because of the Turkish chars since those are not considered as 1 char size. So the field size is 50 and content size is also 50 but contains one or more Turkish chars, so the actual size is more than 50. In this case, PDO simply ignores the field. I solved it with casting higher size thanks to your comment.

Comment: I am using Unix ODBC Driver and I will continue to investigate issue to find out more reliable solution. However, I wanted to post here for future readers and also upvote your comment. Thanks again.